# Plesk hosting is giving Security Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, plesk

Even CAS trust level is set Full.

[image]

Before on other Plesk hosting it was working fine . but this shared hosting is givivng error

Need solution for this

Server Error in '/' Application.
    Security Exception
    Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

```
Exception Details:
```

System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

```
Source Error:   
Line 1:  
Line 2:  @{ 
Line 3:      Layout = null;
Line 4:  }
Line 5:  <body background="~/images/background.jpg" style="margin:100px">

Source File: d:\inetpub\vhosts\mysitename.com\httpdocs\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 3
```

---

```
Stack Trace: 


[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet ) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark ) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Web.HttpContext.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type service) +54
   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService(Type serviceType) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn(HttpContextBase httpContext) +108
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +138
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +103
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String basePath, String path, Object[] pathParts) +144
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Href(String path, Object[] pathParts) +44
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in d:\inetpub\vhosts\naqshbandimohsinilive.com\httpdocs\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:3
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +78
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +293
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +422
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +173
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748669
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0
```

---

Either is this hosting error r some configuration required ? although CAS trust level is set Full.

Comment: Solved :after contacting Administrator get to know that hosting is not enabling Full trust Level.  Issue resolved after changing hosting because MVC5 required CAS trust level is set Full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using hostgator and was getting the code access security error.

*Version Information:Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2623.0*

It was resolved by adding these settinges in web.config file of the project.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <securityPolicy>
            <trustLevel name="Full" policyFile="internal"/>
        </securityPolicy>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am getting this error after setting trustlevel like this  This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using location allowOverride="false" from an inherited configuration file

Answer (score 0):

In case of MVC5+ add this line in Config File

**< trust level="Full" />**

and if after that it gives error on that line in Web.Config. then ask your web hosting admin. because **MVC5** required **CAS trust level is set Full**.